# Uitableview content size issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have an table view which content size is more than the uiview size i could not able to see the last cell fully as table view is not scrolling up to the tableview cell .

Comment: And why don't you set the desired height of the table view? Have you tried, and you have any problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using autolayout then you need to set bottom space from super view = 0 in your xib. For more info see in this pic.
[image]

And if you are not using autolayout then you can set frame direct of your tableview.

Answer (score 1):

Its appear you had set the `frame` of your `UITableView` Wrongly, if your `UITableView` is full screen, set its frame as following:

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

And so on...

Comment: Isn't the self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds; shorter version of your code?